# How are sessions maintained after login authentication?

Tags: session, authentication

After the username password login form is submitted (presumably with some kind of encryption through https) how does the server maintain the information that the user is logged in?

The user submits the login form and the server authenticates the user and returns a page. But when the user clicks on a link on that page how does the server know the request it is receiving is coming from someone who is authenticated and therefore the server knows its safe to send the html for that new page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The act of logging on will usually result in the browser getting a session cookie passed back.  It's this cookie that the server uses to identify which session (if any) belongs to the user.

If cookies are disabled on the clients browser, most web programming frameworks will cope by sticking a session ID onto the URL.

Comment: So this cookie comes along with every http request the user makes to the server? Where in the html is sending the cookie to the server specified?

Comment: @user, the cookie is part of the HTTP request header, and the browser deals with ensuring that this cookie is placed in each and every request back to the server _for the particular site_.

Comment: So its part of the HTTP protocol that the cookie is automatically put into the http request?

Comment: @user, possibly / probably - I'm no HTTP request guru I'm afraid.  It's standard behaviour, though.

Comment: So what does a cookie look like, is it an encrypted string or just a round brown crispy thing.

Answer (score 0):

the username and some flag like is_logged are stored in the session.
on any page you should check those variables from the current session.
on logout you clean the session or destroy it, thus your protected page is in accessible.
good luck

Arman